# Simple Upload Adapter, ckeditor Couldn't upload file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ckeditor

All are working, but when I upload image, I get this error.

[image]

I can't find any information about this error. I found many similar solutions, but none worked.

It's my code. I use Express.js with ejs.
This is addPost.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <%- include('./blocks/header.ejs') %>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="editor">
        <p>Enter text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%- include('./blocks/footer.ejs') %>
    <script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
      InlineEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ),
            {
              toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'exportPDF','exportWord', '|',
                        'findAndReplace', 'selectAll', '|',
                        'heading', '|',
                        'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'code', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'removeFormat', '|',
                        'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', '|',
                        'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                        'undo', 'redo',
                        '-',
                        'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', 'highlight', '|',
                        'alignment', '|',
                        'link', 'insertImage', 'blockQuote', 'insertTable', 'mediaEmbed', 'codeBlock', 'htmlEmbed', '|',
                        'specialCharacters', 'horizontalLine', 'pageBreak', '|',
                        'textPartLanguage', '|',
                        'sourceEditing'
                    ],
                    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
                },
                heading: {
                    options: [
                        { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                        { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                        { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
                        { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Heading 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
                        { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Heading 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
                        { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Heading 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
                        { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Heading 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' }
                    ]
                }
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is src/ckeditor.js

```js
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2014-2022, CKSource Holding sp. z o.o. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */
import InlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-inline/src/inlineeditor.js';
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment.js';
import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat.js';
import AutoImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/autoimage.js';
import AutoLink from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/autolink.js';
import Autosave from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autosave/src/autosave.js';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote.js';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold.js';
import CloudServices from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services/src/cloudservices.js';
import Code from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/code.js';
import CodeBlock from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock.js';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js';
import FindAndReplace from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-find-and-replace/src/findandreplace.js';
import FontBackgroundColor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontbackgroundcolor.js';
import FontColor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontcolor.js';
import FontFamily from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontfamily.js';
import FontSize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontsize.js';
import GeneralHtmlSupport from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support/src/generalhtmlsupport.js';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading.js';
import Highlight from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight/src/highlight.js';
import HorizontalLine from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-horizontal-line/src/horizontalline.js';
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image.js';
import ImageCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption.js';
import ImageInsert from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageinsert.js';
import ImageResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize.js';
import ImageStyle from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle.js';
import ImageToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar.js';
import ImageUpload from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload.js';
import Indent from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indent.js';
import IndentBlock from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indentblock.js';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic.js';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link.js';
import LinkImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/linkimage.js';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list.js';
import ListProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/listproperties.js';
import MediaEmbed from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembed.js';
import MediaEmbedToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembedtoolbar.js';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph.js';
import PasteFromOffice from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/src/pastefromoffice.js';
import RemoveFormat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format/src/removeformat.js';
import SpecialCharacters from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacters.js';
import SpecialCharactersArrows from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersarrows.js';
import SpecialCharactersCurrency from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterscurrency.js';
import SpecialCharactersEssentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersessentials.js';
import SpecialCharactersLatin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterslatin.js';
import SpecialCharactersMathematical from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersmathematical.js';
import SpecialCharactersText from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterstext.js';
import Strikethrough from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/strikethrough.js';
import Style from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-style/src/style.js';
import Subscript from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/subscript.js';
import Superscript from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/superscript.js';
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table.js';
import TableCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecaption.js';
import TableCellProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecellproperties';
import TableColumnResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecolumnresize.js';
import TableProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tableproperties';
import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar.js';
import TextTransformation from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing/src/texttransformation.js';
import Title from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/title.js';
import Underline from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline.js';
import WordCount from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-word-count/src/wordcount.js';
import SimpleUploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter';

class Editor extends InlineEditor {}

// Plugins to include in the build.
Editor.builtinPlugins = [
    Alignment,
    Autoformat,
    AutoImage,
    AutoLink,
    Autosave,
    BlockQuote,
    Bold,
    CloudServices,
    Code,
    CodeBlock,
    Essentials,
    FindAndReplace,
    FontBackgroundColor,
    FontColor,
    FontFamily,
    FontSize,
    GeneralHtmlSupport,
    Heading,
    Highlight,
    HorizontalLine,
    Image,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageInsert,
    ImageResize,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    IndentBlock,
    Italic,
    Link,
    LinkImage,
    List,
    ListProperties,
    MediaEmbed,
    MediaEmbedToolbar,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromOffice,
    RemoveFormat,
    SpecialCharacters,
    SpecialCharactersArrows,
    SpecialCharactersCurrency,
    SpecialCharactersEssentials,
    SpecialCharactersLatin,
    SpecialCharactersMathematical,
    SpecialCharactersText,
    Strikethrough,
    Style,
    Subscript,
    Superscript,
    Table,
    TableCaption,
    TableCellProperties,
    TableColumnResize,
    TableProperties,
    TableToolbar,
    TextTransformation,
    Title,
    Underline,
    WordCount,
    SimpleUploadAdapter
];

// Editor configuration.
Editor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'strikethrough',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            '|',
            'alignment',
            'outdent',
            'indent',
            '|',
            'codeBlock',
            'imageUpload',
            'imageInsert',
            'blockQuote',
            'insertTable',
            'mediaEmbed',
            'undo',
            'redo',
            '-',
            'fontBackgroundColor',
            'fontColor',
            'fontFamily',
            'fontSize',
            '|',
            'horizontalLine',
            'specialCharacters',
            'highlight',
            'removeFormat',
            'superscript',
            'subscript',
            '|',
            'findAndReplace',
            'style'
        ],
        shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
    },
    language: 'ru',
    image: {
        toolbar: [
            'imageTextAlternative',
            'imageStyle:inline',
            'imageStyle:block',
            'imageStyle:side',
            'linkImage'
        ],
        upload: {
            types: [ 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp' ]
        }
    },
    table: {
        contentToolbar: [
            'tableColumn',
            'tableRow',
            'mergeTableCells',
            'tableCellProperties',
            'tableProperties'
        ]
    },
    simpleUpload: {
        uploadUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'CSRF-Token',
            Authorization: 'Bearer <JSON Web Token>'
        }
    }
};

export default Editor;
```

That's all what I've done.
Hope for help)

Answer (score 0):

From this [line](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/b2fe163a55f83e6e5d8c829e237c23cb3f08102a/packages/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter.ts#L215) of `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload` package:

```js
// Prepare the form data.
const data = new FormData();

data.append( 'upload', file );

// Send the request.
this.xhr!.send( data );
```

We know the form field name for the upload file is `upload`. Remember this, We will use this field name on our server side.

Now, let's write code for the server side, I will use the `express` web framework and some middleware to build the upload service.

`app.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

let imageName = '';
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: path.resolve(__dirname, 'uploads/'),
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    imageName = Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, imageName);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('upload');

app.use(cors());
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

app.get('/ok', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ error: { message: 'image upload failed' } });
    res.json({
      url: `http://localhost:${port}/uploads/${imageName}`,
    });
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server is listening on port 5000'));
```

You need to use [`.single(fieldname)`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#singlefieldname) of `multer`, the `fieldname` should be `'upload'` as mentioned above.

Besides, the server-side is available on `http://localhost:5000`, and client-side is available on `http://localhost:8080`. There will be a CORS issue when using `XMLHttpRequest` to send the HTTP request. So we can use `cors` middleware to handle the CORS.

Client-side:

`ckeditor.ts`:

```
import { ClassicEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic';

import { UploadAdapter } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder';
import { Alignment } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment';
import { Autoformat } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat';
import { Autosave } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autosave';
import { Bold, Code, Italic, Strikethrough, Underline } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles';
import { BlockQuote } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote';
import { CloudServices } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services';
import { Essentials } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials';
import { FindAndReplace } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-find-and-replace';
import { FontBackgroundColor, FontColor, FontFamily, FontSize, Font } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font';
import { Heading } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading';
import { HorizontalLine } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-horizontal-line';
import { HtmlEmbed } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-embed';
import { DataFilter, DataSchema, GeneralHtmlSupport, HtmlComment } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support';
import { AutoImage, Image, ImageCaption, ImageInsert, ImageResize, ImageStyle, ImageToolbar, ImageUpload } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image';
import { Indent, IndentBlock } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent';
import { AutoLink, Link, LinkImage } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link';
import { List, ListProperties } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list';
import { Paragraph } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph';
import { PasteFromOffice } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office';
import { RemoveFormat } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format';
import { StandardEditingMode } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-restricted-editing';
import {
  SpecialCharacters,
  SpecialCharactersArrows,
  SpecialCharactersCurrency,
  SpecialCharactersEssentials,
  SpecialCharactersLatin,
  SpecialCharactersMathematical,
  SpecialCharactersText,
} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters';
import { Table, TableCaption, TableCellProperties, TableColumnResize, TableProperties, TableToolbar } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table';
import { TextTransformation } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing';
import { WordCount } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-word-count';
import { SimpleUploadAdapter } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload';

class Editor extends ClassicEditor {
  public static override builtinPlugins = [
    Alignment,
    AutoImage,
    AutoLink,
    Autoformat,
    Autosave,
    BlockQuote,
    Bold,
    CloudServices,
    Code,
    DataFilter,
    DataSchema,
    Essentials,
    FindAndReplace,
    Font,
    FontBackgroundColor,
    FontColor,
    FontFamily,
    FontSize,
    GeneralHtmlSupport,
    Heading,
    HorizontalLine,
    HtmlComment,
    HtmlEmbed,
    Image,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageInsert,
    ImageResize,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    IndentBlock,
    Italic,
    Link,
    LinkImage,
    List,
    ListProperties,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromOffice,
    RemoveFormat,
    SpecialCharacters,
    SpecialCharactersArrows,
    SpecialCharactersCurrency,
    SpecialCharactersEssentials,
    SpecialCharactersLatin,
    SpecialCharactersMathematical,
    SpecialCharactersText,
    StandardEditingMode,
    Strikethrough,
    Table,
    TableCaption,
    TableCellProperties,
    TableColumnResize,
    TableProperties,
    TableToolbar,
    TextTransformation,
    Underline,
    UploadAdapter,
    WordCount,
    SimpleUploadAdapter,
  ];

  public static override defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
      items: [
        'heading',
        '|',
        'fontSize',
        'fontColor',
        'fontBackgroundColor',
        '|',
        'bold',
        'italic',
        'underline',
        'strikethrough',
        'link',
        '|',
        'alignment:left',
        'alignment:right',
        'alignment:center',
        'alignment:justify',
        '|',
        'findAndReplace',
        'horizontalLine',
        '|',
        'bulletedList',
        'numberedList',
        '|',
        'outdent',
        'indent',
        '|',
        'removeFormat',
        'imageUpload',
        'blockQuote',
        'insertTable',
        'mediaEmbed',
        '|',
        'undo',
        'redo',
      ],
    },
    simpleUpload: {
      uploadUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/upload',
    },
    heading: {
      options: [
        { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
        { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
        { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
        { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Heading 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
        { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Heading 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
        { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Heading 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
        { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Heading 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' },
      ],
    } as any,
    fontSize: {
      options: [9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 26, 28],
      supportAllValues: true,
    },
    image: {
      toolbar: ['imageTextAlternative', 'toggleImageCaption', 'imageStyle:inline', 'imageStyle:block', 'imageStyle:side', 'linkImage'],
    },
    table: {
      contentToolbar: ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'tableCellProperties', 'tableProperties'],
    },
  };
}

export default Editor;
```

After adding the `SimpleUploadAdapter` to plugins, the `simpleUpload` configuration is:

```js
simpleUpload: {
    uploadUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/upload',
}
```

Now we can upload the image successfully.

[image]

I post full code on [GitHub](https://github.com/mrdulin/ckeditor5-39.0.2)